# How do make a dictionary app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary

I was thinking of making a dictionary app for my Objectiv C classes that I use, sort of a cheat sheet.

I want to be something like this;

Class --> Code Sample

Basically, a scroll view of the classes, then I can choose one that I want to know how to implement and then I get a complete code sample.

Anyone?

David.

Comment: UITableView -> UIScrollView with example code within it

Comment: Either this is terribly simple or awfully difficult. If you want to type in all the text yourself, then it's just a simple UITableview app. Otherwise if you want to automate the textmaking it woun't be easy. I don't know if something like Doxygen can help.

Comment: @David: it's not clear whether the difficulty you're asking about it is the overall structure of the application, or whether you'd like to do runtime type introspection on your classes and auto-generate the data, and that's tricky for you, or what. You'd get more directed answers if you clarify.

Comment: We can't write your app for you. Are you asking us how to architecture the app or ???

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Doxygen?  It sounds like what you want is a way to generate code documentation automatically.

Check out    http://www.jiggerjuice.net/software/doxygen.html for a good tutorial on how it works and see if it's right for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to build something very similar to [runtimebrowser](http://code.google.com/p/runtimebrowser/). That's open source, so you should definitely peek around to get ideas.